# Does 1 Corinthians 13:1 indicate the existence of ‘angelic’ languages?

Tags: language

> “If I speak in the **tongues** of men and **of angels**, but have not love, I am a noisy gong or a clanging cymbal.”
> ‭‭1 Corinthians‬ ‭13:1‬ ‭

Is this sufficient proof that there are angelic languages? If so what was Paul basing this on? Any OT examples or extraBiblical sources from antiquity that Paul could be relying on?

If this is a hyperbole, how is one to understand tongues of men for they clearly exist? While the first three verses evidently used exaggerations it does not do so with fictitious examples, except possibly languages of the divine beings/ heavenly hosts.

Comment: I think this is likely Paul referencing the claims that some of the Corinthians were making, or hearing made, regarding 'tongue speakers'.  He was not willing to declare that they were not or could not speak thus but outlined spiritual constraints as to proper usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Angelic Languages

The human tongues should be separated with the angelic ones which cannot be interpreted. The commands of orderly speaking of tongues, insisting for interpretation are for the human tongues meant for edification as a miracle for someone else, and especially for an assembly, in 1Cor 14. The restrictions also implies potential misuse & pretence of tongues by man. Paul clearly forbade unnecessary and excessive tongues in the assembly by limiting the number & asking to produce interpretation, yet encouraged the general speaking of tongues. Paul was not concerned of asking a proof of miraculous tongues, yet he subtly restricted potential wrongdoers by issuing limitations and meaningfulness in the usage. It doesn't contradict the other references that presumes the esoteric heavenly languages unintelligible to man.

As proven by others that [2Cor 12:4](https://www.stepbible.org/?q=version=ESV%7Cversion=NETfull%7Cversion=THGNT%7Cversion=DRC%7Cversion=VulgJ%7Cversion=YLT%7Creference=1Cor.13.1%201Cor.14.2%202Cor.12.4&options=NGVUVH&display=INTERLEAVED) and 1Cor 14:2 demonstrate that the angelic tongues are indeed spoken by men, contrary to the assumption that 1 Cor 13:1 implies a hyperbolic fiction of angelic languages.

To add further to their points, I think 2 Cor 12:4 should be clarified:

> NASB "was caught up into Paradise and heard inexpressible words, which a man is not permitted to speak.",
> NJB "words said that cannot and may not be spoken by any human being."
> YLT "unutterable sayings, that it is not possible for man to speak."
> ὅτι ἡρπάγη εἰς τὸν παράδεισον καὶ ἤκουσεν **ἄρρητα** ῥήματα ἃ οὐκ **ἐξὸν** ἀνθρώπῳ λαλῆσαι.

That the words described inexpressible and unlawful for man to speak, are not for being secretive, but for being indiscernible by the virtue of being heavenly. Both Greek words for inexpressible and unlawful should not be understood in the scope of permission in the modern sense (too sacred to utter), but they include the sense of inconceivable and impossible. ἄρρητος is defined in LSJ as:

> __II that cannot be spoken or expressed, ἀδιανόητον καὶ ἄ. καὶ ἄφθεγκτον καὶ ἄλογον[Refs 5th c.BC+]: hence, unspeakable, immense, [Refs 1st c.BC+]
> __IV of numbers, ἄρρητα, τά, irrationals, surds, opposed to ῥητά, [Refs 5th c.BC+]

Mounce and LSJ includes "possible" for the other word ἔξεστι:

> it is legal, it is proper, it is permitted 3rd person sing of the unused ἔξειμι ( 1997) used impersonally, **it is possible**; it is permitted, it is lawful,proper, permitted Mt. 12:2, 4; Mk. 3:4; Lk. 6:9; Acts 22:25; 1Cor. 6:12

Hence, it seems that the language encountered by the individual mentioned in 2 Corinthians 12:4 was not comprehensible to him due to its heavenly nature, rather than being withheld for its secretive content. The concept of "unlawfulness" here refers to an inherent inability to understand these celestial matters. The *permission* should be understood as "not granted the ability to speak", rather than being "forbidden to reveal".

> Is this sufficient proof that there are angelic languages? If so what was Paul basing this on? Any OT examples or extraBiblical sources from antiquity that Paul could be relying on?

Paul was not relying on any particular text, but on various sources and general knowledge about angelic languages. Google books advance search showed some references like Bava Basra 134, that Hillel's least of the 80 students knew all the written and oral torah, and even the language of angels. There is certainly a concept of angelic language here, even though it is clearly a hyperbolic reference.

In *[The Tongues of Angels The Concept of Angelic Languages in Classical Jewish and Christian Texts](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Tongues_of_Angels/DaiujgJQ2aMC?hl=en)* 2010, John Poirier discusses in chap 4 "The Esoteric Heavenly Language:Fairly Certain Cases":

> those texts that contain relatively certain references (viz. 1 Cor 13.1, 2 Cor 12.1–7, Testament of Job, Apocalypse of Zephaniah, Ascension of Isaiah, Apocalypse of Abraham, a saying attributed to R. Hama b. Hanina [in Gen. Rab. 74.7], Ephrem Syrus’ Hymn 11, and the Book of the Resurrection [attributed to Bartholomew]). In most of the pseudepigraphic texts in this list, reference to an esoteric angelic language is connected to the protagonist’s participation in that language, often as a mark
> of achieving “isangelic status” (viz. of being temporarily imbued with angelic qualities).2 One must wonder to what degree the authors of other pseudepigraphic works (viz. those devoid of any such descriptions of humans joining in angelic praise) might have accepted the view that angels spoke an esoteric language

It includes the [Testament of Job](https://charlesasullivan.com/14354/the-testament-of-job-and-angelic-tongues/), which mentions "dialects of the cherubim" and other specific references of esoteric angelic language in Christian and Jewish sources. He has another chapter that discusses less certain references of angelloglossy. "These include the Qumran Songs of the Sabbath Sacrifice, R. Yochanan b. Zakkai’s legendary mastery of the “conversation” of angels, demons, and palm trees (b. B. Bat. 134a || b. Sukkah 28a), the fourth-century Nanas inscription (from Kotiaeion, Asia Minor), and the Christian liturgical jubilus".

It seems evident that there was a concept of esoteric angelic language, unknown and inconceivable to men. In the references of Paul, we see that the heavenly tongues were spoken by men.

Comment: ῥητῶς Means to express and the prefix a indicated the inability to express. I buy it.

Answer (score 4):

Does 1 Corinthians 13:1 indicate the existence of ‘angelic’ languages?

I don't think by analyzing the Greek syntax and semantics themselves, one can prove without a doubt the existence of angelic languages. However, it is natural to understand it as such even just reading the verse by itself.

Further, Paul had experienced this angelic language some 14 years earlier.

> 2 Corinthians 12:1 I must go on boasting. Although there is nothing to be gained, I will go on to visions and revelations from the Lord. 2I know a man in Christ who fourteen years ago was caught up to the **third heaven**. Whether it was in the body or out of the body I do not know—God knows. 3And I know that this man—whether in the body or apart from the body I do not know, but God knows— 4was caught up to paradise and **heard inexpressible things**, things that no one is permitted to tell.

More evidence is found in 1 Corinthians 14:2

> For anyone who speaks in a tongue does **not** speak to people but to God. Indeed, **no one** understands them; they utter mysteries by the Spirit.

No human understands these utterances.

Comment: The things heard in the third heaven are 'inexpressible' because they are not permissible. Not because they were not understood. Had they not been understood in the first place there was no need to forbid what could not be expressed because there was no possibility that such things as could not be understood could ever be told.

Answer (score 4):

**Is this sufficient proof that there are angelic languages?**

> If I speak in **the tongues** of men and of angels, but have not love, I
> am a noisy gong or a clanging cymbal. ‭‭1 Corinthians‬ ‭13:1‬ ESV

I believe angels have a language not languages!
The word translated as tongues is **glossa [G1100](https://biblehub.com/greek/1100.htm)** which means the **tongue, or a language** so one could read it “If I speak in the languages of men and of angels” This vers clearly indicates that angels have their own language, but one vers alone is not enough.

**If so what was Paul basing this on? Any OT examples or extraBiblical sources from antiquity that Paul could be relying on?**

There are verses that state that angels speak to humans and other verses that the angels praises God, some verses mentions to us that they speak between each other in the OT. Angel talks to humans [Gen 18:2-3, 19:1-2, Jdg 6:11-12, Jdg 13:3, Zech 1:9, Dan 7:16,](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Gen+18%3A2-3%2C+19%3A1-2%2C+Jdg+6%3A11-12%2C+Jdg+13%3A3%2C+Zech+1%3A9%2C+Dan+7%3A16%2C&version=ESV) angels praising God [Isaiah 6:2-3, Psalm 103:20, Psalm 148:2](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%206%3A2-3%2C%20Psalm%20103%3A20%2C%20Psalm%20148%3A2&version=esv), God talks to the angels [Genesis 11:7, 1 Kings 22:20, 2 Chronicles 18:19, Job 1:6-22](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2011%3A7%2C%201%20Kings%2022%3A20%2C%202%20Chronicles%2018%3A19%2C%20Job%201%3A6-22&version=ESV).

When angels interact with humans, this has most likely been done in their own tongue with Abraham maybe that was in Akkadian and also to Lot in an unknown tongue but to Gideon, Manoah's wife, Zechariah, Daniel. (NT Zachariah, Mary & John) in Hebrew.

In the Jewish midrash (Bereishit Rabbah 38) it state that God thought his divine language to Adam and that's why he used Hebrew words in Gen 2:23 He called her isha (woman) because "she was taken from ish (man)," Gen 3:20 he called her Chava (Eve) because "she was to be Mother of all chai (life)" this hypothesis (tradition) is called Adamic language. It could be that the Godhead or the angel of the Presence (Hebrew: Mal'akh HaPanim, מלאך הפנים) spoke Hebrew with Adam & Eve, Cain, Noah Abraham & Sara, Hagar, Moses and Samuel.

The question stil remains when the Godhead (The Father, the Son & the Holy Spirit), the archangels, cherubim, seraphim and ophanim talk to each other and when they sing praises to God is this done in a strange language or do they speak Hebrew in the heaven.

> Was caught up into Paradise and heard inexpressible words, which a man
> is not permitted to speak.
> 2 Corinthians 12:4 NASB

Paul didn't understand when the heavenly beings spoke to each other, it can't be Hebrew, he would understand as well be allowed to utter it again, but it's the same as in 1 Cor ‭13:1 tongue of angels, 1 Cor 14:2 "tongue of God", a holy language he only speaks when he's moved by the Holy Spirit not on his own accord regardless if he doesn't understand it or not.

> For the one who speaks in a tongue does not speak to people, but to God; for no one understands, but in his spirit he speaks mysteries. 1 Corinthians 14:2

> If anyone speaks in a tongue, it must be by two or at the most three,
> and each one in turn, and one is to interpret; 28 but if there is no
> interpreter, he is to keep silent in church; and have him speak to
> himself and to God. 1 Corinthians 14:27-28

So when the Holy Spirit moves Paul he speaks in a tongue that he himself doesn't even understands, while in the tongue of men requires interpreters that understands the tongue spoken. 1 Cor 14:27 is the same as in 14:21 *In the Law it is written, “By people of strange tongues and by the lips of foreigners will I speak to this people”* it's talking of languages, also in Acts 2:4, 6-11 it's foreign languages being spoken for all to understand and to work as a sign.

**CONCLUSION;** They speak in a language [tongue] not understandable by man.

Answer (score 2):

The apostles spoke in the languages of other nations on the day of Pentecost.

If it is the case that some misunderstood, and if it went abroad during those times that 'men can speak in the tongues of angels', then Paul would be aware of such misunderstanding and rather than cause a great deal of strife about something that is difficult (or impossible) to actually 'prove', he might choose not to argue but to avoid the whole contention.

We see him regulate any such occurrence by requiring that any speech 'in an unknown tongue' must be interpreted, not by the speaker (who could make something up) but by another witness who must be able to understand the 'tongue'.

And we see Paul state that, even if he spoke in the tongue of angels (though he does not state that he does so, or even could so) yet did so without charity, it would be worthless.

Then, in Paul's later epistles, particularly his last to Timothy, he mentions nothing about the subject when exhorting pastoral care to either Timothy or Titus.

Nor does John, ever, mention the subject in any of his writings which came at the end of the first century and after the departure of the other apostles.

To me, this all points in a certain direction.

But, like Paul, I choose not to enter into contention or strife on the matter, but just to  state the obvious.

Comment: Was hoping for a direct answer but this will suffice until one such answer shall come in the future

Comment: @NihilSineDeo Thank you for the acceptance. My own view is that Paul, himself, does not directly confront the question. Thus my own is as it is. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that 1st Corinthians 14:2 defends the "tongues of angels" many Christians speak today that are not actual human languages.  I myself am an Apostolic Oneness Christian to be specific, but I just usually say "Christian".  This helped answer the question I had in another forum.

Many Christians seem to commonly misunderstand one thing, there is a difference between needing someone else present who has the "gift of interpretation" of a tongue in relation to "*prophecy*" for a congregation, and that tongues are used differently as tools and evidence in other situations.  The common misconception is there always needs to be an interpreter in *all* situations where tongues are spoken, which is not true (see 1st Corinthians 14).  As mentioned before, only in cases of *prophecy* does there need to be another person who has the gift of interpretation.  The tongue(s) which do *not* need someone with the gift of interpretation is found in two general contexts:

1. When someone experiences the infilling of the Holy Ghost/Spirit by way of either being prayed through to the Spirit baptism (see Cornelius in Acts 10) and is then water baptized in Jesus' name, or someone who is baptized in Jesus' name and then receives the Holy Ghost/Spirit baptism (Acts 2:36-39, Acts 19:1-6, John 3:5).  No matter the route, these can **never** preceed repentance of sins (the "changing of mind" about sin).

   Please note: tongues are the "initial" sign of receiving the Holy Ghost (see Acts 2:4), but they are **not the only sign of having** the Holy Ghost (see Galatians 5:22-23, Matthew 7:16-20)

**and/or**

2. When a speaker of an unknown tongue is being edified by the Holy Ghost in times of prayer and worship.  The Holy Ghost also prays things through us in groanings when we know not what to pray for (see Romans 8:26).

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: May I enquire if the question you had in another forum was ChatGPT?

Comment: Hello, Lesley.  No, I have actually never used ChatGPT before, the last place I asked this question (which was a bit of a long time ago now, but I still remember asking it) was a thread on Reddit where similar discussions were being had.

Answer (score 0):

If angels exist, and they do, then they being intellectual bodiless creatures should be able to communicate with God, praising Him (Rev. 4:8), and with each other (Jude 1:9). Having neither physical tongues nor physical ears with membranes etc. their communication does not happen in any audible form, by a medium of air molecules, but in another form, with another medium. Thus, hosts of angels can be in our room, communicate with each other most vividly and we may not even notice them. Of course by a special dispensation Lord can make their “voices” be heard by our physical ears, like the shepherds heard them singing in contemporary Aramaic at the Lord’s birth in Bethlehem.

Even in human relationships not all communication is in language, but the most sublime is through glance into one-another's eyes, or even a gesture, a smile, a frown etc. How much more so with the angels! But since our intelligent souls are of the same contemplative substance as that of angels, so also our souls can understand supra-verbal angelic tongue, but it is ***one only tongue***, one grammar-less and syntax-less language, and there are not many languages for angels of different heavenly nationalities for all angels belong to one nation of contemplative intellects praising ceaselessly God whose features they contemplate.

We all know this tongue: when we are immersed in a deep and kind contemplation, before even expressing it in words, in a poem, for instance, or in a philosophical discourse, it is there as "logos endiathetos" pre-utterably or even unatterably in our souls. It can be uttered and expressed to a degree in all human languages, but in its core remains silent and inexpressible in fullness, and it transcends all national or tribal languages, while the tribe of angels understands it without grammar and syntax of English, Georgian, Armenian or any other language.

Comment: I don’t believe you can call heavenly beings specifically angels/aggelos /messengers bodiless, for they interact with the natural realm quite well, striking Peter in the side for example. In 1Cor15:40 there we see the reference to heavenly BODIES. The only bodiless beings are the demons who are the left over souls of the Nephilim, they crave a body to inhabit and manifest through but heavenly beings have no such craving. The utterance without words is not a language per se, it’s an expression. You seem to be implying a type of telepathy. Angels have their own language or languages.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo Thanks for the response! The 1 Cor 15:40 is about stars and planets. Yes, angels can by permission of Lord Jesus Christ acquire bodily shape and interact with physical world physically, but in their essence they are supra-material, no angel can be harmed by whatever most refined and intricate weapon created, say, in the year 5708 by most advanced nanotechnological experiments. Demons are just fallen versions of angels, and neither demons nor angels have bodies.

Comment: I disagree vehemently with your assessment that supernatural anngels are without bodies. I already voted on your post and this is just a point that I disagree with in your response. You have no proof of God letting angels “acquire” a body. And your point about demons I only partially agree. The Nephilim who were the result of human and angelic union didn’t have their names written in the lambs book of life from before the foundation of the world and they consequently when they perished in the flood lost their bodies but they could not return to God so they remained on earth and crave a housing

Comment: @NihilSineDeo i haven’t said that angels acquire body but a visibility of body, a bodily shape, and visibility of vestments also, for they are dressed up; as it is wrong to say that their vestments are prepared in heavenly textile factories out of wool of heavenly sheep grazing silver linings of luminous clouds, so it is wrong to say that any earthly stylist can trim hairs of angels with his scissors, or comb them with a plastic comb. Again, even in the year 8075 with ceaseless tech. development humans cannot invent a weapon - chemical, nuclear or biological - to harm angels.

Comment: That’s because they are SUPRAnatural above the natural and not limited to the laws of nature and what I’m saying is that they already possess a body, a supernatural body that is not confined and limited to the laws of nature like a natural body is. I guess we are coming into agreement.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo i do agree that there is a certain limitedness, that is to say, confinement and “body”-ness in angels as well as demons, for only Father, Son and H.Ghost are limitless and ubiquitous, and as such, completely bodyless (sorry Mormons,  your idea of God’s corporeality is a childish imagination, utterly wrong and heretical for that matter!). Indeed, a legion of demons entered (approx 2000-5000) in one poor man, thus they have very special subtle bodies, just as angels do.