# "tongues of men" versus the "tongues of angels" is there a noticeable and Biblical difference?

Tags: 1-corinthians, tongue

> Though I speak with the tongues of men and of angels, and have not charity, I am become as sounding brass, or a tinkling cymbal. (1 Corinthians 13:1 KJV)

> Ἐὰν ταῖς γλώσσαις τῶν ἀνθρώπων λαλῶ καὶ τῶν ἀγγέλων, ἀγάπην δὲ μὴ ἔχω, γέγονα χαλκὸς ἠχῶν ἢ κύμβαλον ἀλαλάζον.

Is there a Greek or Hebrew root wording to signify that the "tongues of angels" are the unknown tongues, i.e. indiscernible to humans?

Comment: How would we even know - how could we confirm this?

Comment: The language of 1 Cor 13:1 sounds just like simple hyperbole and so shoud not be taken literally because it is a figure of speech.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does 1 Corinthians 13:1 indicate the existence of ‘angelic’ languages?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/55525/does-1-corinthians-131-indicate-the-existence-of-angelic-languages)

Comment: @Michael16 You've really been helpful here. That other question is very much related. My answer here is basically that that other question is where we will find the detailed answers, not from the dictionaries. Thank you.

Comment: This is a good question. It's not lazy. It's not a pure duplicate. If others strongly disagree, let me know and we can discuss it and involve the other mods. But, I have had this curiosity myself in my Bible studies: *How much can the dictionaries speak to this topic?* That's good thinking in the hermeneutical process.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a good question, rephrased: *Do we get this idea from the original language dictionaries? Or, do we only get it from somewhere else?*

The short answer is: Somewhere else, viz [this question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/55525/27581).

Basically, as I know from study in college and different views as regularly discussed among different denominations, it's based on sentences and cross-references. The word "tongues" simply either means "the human tongue" or also "language". There's not much more to it than that. Any more meaning needs a sentence.

The New Testament word is Greek, not Hebrew. That other question looks at the Old Testament in a very thorough way, but not for the specific question you are asking since that didn't happen in the Old Testament. It didn't even happen during Jesus's earthly ministry, but only after Acts 2. So, for your question, the only answers will be in Greek.

γλῶσσα (glóssa) **[Strong's 1100](https://biblehub.com/greek/1100.htm)**

> the tongue, a language

That's pretty much it as far as dictionaries go.

If you review a theological dictionary, you will get lots of elaboration on uses and how it can mean some kind of "unintelligible prayer language", but all of those examples look at the sentences, mainly stories from the [Book of Acts](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%201&version=NASB1995). Those meanings don't come from any Greek lexicon or dictionary, but only from the sentences and paragraphs explaining an idea.

The most we get for any kind of description is from Romans.

**Romans 8:26** ([NASB](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%208%3A26&version=NASB1995))

> In the same way the Spirit also helps our weakness; for we do not know how to pray as we should, but the Spirit Himself intercedes for us with groanings too deep for words;

Even then, there is debate among Bible teachers about whether Paul is talking about the prayer language (unintelligible) "tongues" or just a feeling that the Holy Spirit takes care of because He knows our hearts. If you want to look more at that, you can read [that separate question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/55525/27581) about how those texts might build a case for "tongues of angels".

There really isn't much beyond that (and 1 Cor 13:1 as you cited) to objectively resolve the difference between a "tongue of men" vs a "tongue of angels".

Comment: Thank you, Jesse.  I do believe that Romans 8:26 makes a strong case for tongues sounding much like the tongues usually prayed by Pentecostals/Oneness Apostolics.  I am an Apostolic Christian, and I am sympathetic to people who are not sure what edifying tongues sound like.  I pray in those sorts of tongues as the Holy Ghost moves up and out of me, and I feel stronger after doing so, because that is a major purpose for those tongues - edification.  It's also for Jesus, being the salvific name of God, pray things which are important to pray for at the time when you don't know what to pray for.

Comment: @ZacharyTheriault I am familiar with the Apostolic/Oneness movement, one of their pastors is a good friend. With me, you're in good company, we just want to avoid too much debating on this site while remaining respectful. Let me know if you ever have trouble. If you like an answer, remember you can vote it up or click the checkmark to mark it as the main accepted answer. Glad to have you join us!

Comment: Thank you, Jesse!  Wow, it is actually so refreshing and relieving to be in the company of someone who is not necessarily a Oneness Apostolic themselves but is so gracious and open-minded towards them.  We get a lot of flack from denominal/Trinitarian people for what we believe, usually because they simply don't understand the Oneness position as being a purely monotheistic position from a Jewish or even Islamic point of view.  Because of the omnipresence of God, the Spirit we call the Father (John 4:24) manifested as and was in Christ and simultaneously in the heavenlies.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @ZacharyTheriault FWIW, my opinion on that is: 1. the word "persons" bugs me because it is an attempt to anthropomorphize God; we need a word other than "persons". 2. The church councils that establish the Trinity (it is a doctrine, not a systematic theology) were refuting angel-Jesus or non-divine Jesus; they were not refuting the tenants of Oneness, so we should keep calm when it comes up. I hope that helps. Welcome.

Comment: This was friendly, and we need friendliness on this site. But let's stop the friendly comments here and move to [The Library](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1505/the-library) or [BH.Meta](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Human tongues are according to Rev 21:17 the same as angelic tongues. However, a tongue can, according to 1 Cor 13:1, also be a "cymbalic" tongue. To be used to confuse, and hinder bad spiritual entities from planting bad thoughts in our minds; among which the dark side of love, lust, is the main problem. Cymbalic talk works as white noise in our minds. And when perfection arrives this kind of spiritual warfare can rest.